# Laravel image submit button

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-3

I'd like to know if there is a way to customize the look of a submit button (to be an Image instead) in [Laravel 3](http://three.laravel.com/docs).

Currently, my submit button code looks like this :

```
{{ Form::open('project/delete', 'DELETE') }}
{{ Form::hidden('id', $project->id) }}
{{ Form::submit('Delete project', array('class'=>'btn')); }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

And it's doing his job correctly. But I don't see how I could customize the submit button and put it as a bootstrap icon for example with ; `<i class="icon-trash"></i>`

I tried using :

```
{{ HTML::decode(HTML::link_to_route('project_delete', '<i class="icon-trash"></i>', array($project->id))); }}
```

But then I have a problem with my route/ function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use HTML for the value of an `input`. If you tried `<input type="submit" value='<i class="icon-trash"></i>'>` you would see it didn't work. Furthermore, using a link like your second approach won't work because it doesn't actually *submit* the form.

Your best bet would be to use a button.

```
<button type="submit"><i class="icon-trash"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `HTML` class to generate a link in this way and it's (`HTML`) been removed from `L4` as best practice, it'll be easier if you use raw `HTML` markup for this, though there are alternative ways like ([bootstrapper](http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/bootstrapper), I didn't tried tho) for this in `L3` but it's overwhelming in (IMO).
Check this [forum link](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=1772).

Alternatively you can use a custom macro, just create a new file (myMacros.php) in `app\libraries`, it should be as `app\libraries\myMacros.php` and put following code in this file

```
HTML::macro('link_nested', function($route, $title = null, $attributes = array(), $secure = null, $nested = null, $params = array()) 
{
    $url = URL::to_route($route, $params, $secure);
    $title = $title ?: $url;
    if (empty($attributes)) {
        $attributes = null;
    }
    return '<a href="'.$url.'"'.HTML::attributes($attributes).'>'.$nested.''.HTML::entities($title).'</a>';
});
```

Then, include it in your `start.php` like

```
require path('app').'/libraries/myMacros.php';
```

Finally, use it ln your template like

```
HTML::link_nested('user.accountview', 'Delete', array('class'=>'btn'), '', '<i class="icon-trash"></i>', array($project->id));
```

For a `submit` button add this in your `myMacros.php`

```
HTML::macro('submit_nested', function($title = null, $attributes = array(), $nested = null) 
{
    $title = $title ?: 'Submit';
    if (empty($attributes)) {
        $attributes = null;
    }
    return '<button type="submit" ' . HTML::attributes($attributes).'>' . $nested  .' '. HTML::entities($title).'</button>';
});
```

Finally, use it like

```
HTML::submit_nested('Search', array('class'=>'someClass', 'name' => 'submit'), '<i class="icon-trash"></i>');
```